# msi can not be installed on win 8.1?

Tags: python, .net, windows, installation

I have installed the win 8.1 professional edition.
But the xx.msi file (i.e., python, .net framework etc.) can not be installed on win 8.1.
When I want to install it, it just terminates quickly. 
Despite of I running it with Administrator role.

So, is there any solutions for installing the xx.msi file on win 8.1?
 Thanks for you attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing would be to check if you have downloaded all the bytes for the .msi.  Then right-click on the .msi file and go to Properties.  Click on the Compatibility tab and select "Run on compatibility mode for".  When I've tried compatibility mode it has not help, but it might for you.  Good luck!

Comment: the problem is solved. when I installed the python.msi, it is python-2.7.10.amd64.msi, which means my computer can not be compatible with the amd. And I download another msi file, the problem is solved. Now, I can  fly with the python again!!!!!